# driver for canon LBP6030 ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, printing, 64-bit, canon

`bash: cd: linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken: No such file or directory`

I checked everything. Have latest updates Ubuntu 16.04.3

```
herman@herman:~$ cd Downloads
herman@herman:~/Downloads$
herman@herman:~/Downloads$ tar -zxvf linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Documents/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Documents/guide-ufr2lt-1.4xUK.tar.gz
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Documents/LICENSE-EN.txt
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Documents/README-ufr2lt-1.4xUK.html
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Sources/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Sources/cndrvcups-common-3.80-1.tar.gz
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Sources/cndrvcups-utility-1.00-1.tar.gz
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/Sources/cndrvcups-sfp-1.40-1.tar.gz
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_ko_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_es_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_de_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_ja_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_zh_CN_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_it_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_fr_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_zh_TW_utf8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/resources/installer_en_utr8.lc
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/RPM/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-common-3.80-1.i386.rpm
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk-1.40-1.i386.rpm
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-utility-1.00-1.i386.rpm
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/Debian/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk_1.40-1_i386.deb
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-utility_1.00-1_i386.deb
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/32-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-common_3.80-1_i386.deb
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/install.sh
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/RPM/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-utility-1.00-1.x86_64.rpm
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk-1.40-1.x86_64.rpm
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/RPM/cndrvcups-common-3.80-1.x86_64.rpm
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-ufr2lt-uk_1.40-1_amd64.deb
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-common_3.80-1_amd64.deb
linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-utility_1.00-1_amd64.deb
herman@herman:~/Downloads$ cd linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken
bash: cd: linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken: No such file or directory herman@herman:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 0):

Canon supply their UFRII driver; I would start here
https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp6030.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit) and click to download and SAVE what is linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz

open a terminal; 
copy the commands below; line by line; 
paste each line into the terminal; and hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz
cd linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken
```

then one runs the install script that should set things up

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

you can check as you go: so if you do `cd Downloads` then if you do `ls` that is asking to LIST what is in the Downloads directory; so if you see linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz listed there, then go on to command 2) where you unpack it with the tar command; linux is very logical; if it says it can't see it or find it; well, it ain't there ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73193/discussion-on-answer-by-pdc-driver-for-canon-lbp6030-ubuntu-16-04-3).